# problems with the write function in c

Tags: c

I want to create text int a file, and this is my code :

```
int ecrire(){
    char buf[1024];
    int bytesStored;
    int fildes;
    char path[128];
    int i=0;
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
    int flags = O_WRONLY;
    printf("\n%s-->Donner l'emplacement du fichier :%s ", CYAN_NORMAL, RESETCOLOR);
    scanf("%s", path);
    fildes = open(path, flags, mode);
    if(fildes == -1){
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n%s-->Enter le contenu pour le fichier%s ", CYAN_NORMAL, RESETCOLOR);
    printf("%s(Appuyer CTRl+D a la fin du fichier) :%s \n", CYAN_UNDERLINE  , RESETCOLOR);
    fflush(stdin);
    while((buf[i] = getc(stdin)) != EOF) i++;
    buf[i] = '\0';
    bytesStored = sizeof(buf);
    if(write(fildes,buf,bytesStored) < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    close(fildes);
    return 1;
}
```

For example, if I write this content :

```
aaaaaaa 
jjjjjjjjj 
@@@@@@@
```

And when I read it I get this :

```
aaaaaaa 
jjjjjjjjj 
@@@@@@@
P�td�=�=�=�w�wQ�td��}�Ya��E}���P�x�ڿ��ڿAa��*}�P���+}���}�x�ڿ�X�t�ڿp�ڿ���|����#a���Aa���ڿ+}�;0~�E�`��
                                                                           �
                                                                            .}�X(}��E}��#a�4C}�x�ڿ��ڿP�D�ڿ�Z���ڿ��}�`�ڿ4C}�h�ڿ�Z.}�\U�
~�x�ڿ��\U�;0~�D�ڿ\U�pS�~�E}�����#a�X(}�p�E}��A~�P�P���a�P�>�}�@���}�� \�P�\r`�+}���}��-}��-}���~���~��D}������F}���h�`���@}�+}�P�I`��M`[~�;H+}�X(}�N��#a� �@{���g�P���ڿ�Z�`�ڿ��}�ڿ ��ڿ�Z�H+}�8Y�}��!�������� J{�����}��fg� J{���ڿ8Y�����I`�N���8����h�`�X(}� J{���g� J{�}�U�g��J{���}�I`��|�sLn�@{�{~g�P�8Y���%~��Z�H+}���g��J{���ڿ�i���ڿ��J{�
```

Why I'm getting this problem, and how can I solve it :

Comment: I smell a missing `'\0'`-terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bytesStored = sizeof(buf);
```

sets `bytesStored` to 1024; and

```
if(write(fildes,buf,bytesStored) < 0){
```

writes just, you know, all of that. Because `buf[]` exists on the stack, there's no guarantees regarding its content, and as you discovered, it's 1024 bytes of garbage.

You probably meant to do something like `strlen(buf)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is bad because getc returns an int, then you store it in char buf[i], then you compare to the int value EOF.

```
(buf[i] = getc(stdin)) != EOF
```

You need to

```
int c;
while((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
   buf[i] = c;
```

Second, you are filling buf until you read EOF, but then you are setting `bytesStored = sizeof(buf);` and so writing out the complete buffer - which is valid at the beginning but uninitialized at the end. So you end up with a file with valid data at the beginning and garbage at the end. You need to set

```
bytesStored = i;
```

Also, cou can eliminate i and directly modify bytesStored.